# I can't update user data by using textfiled

Tags: flutter

I am trying to update the name and phone number of the user, but I am trying to print the change. It is printed null. Can you help
it is my code:

```
class UserProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserProfileState createState() => _UserProfileState();
}

class _UserProfileState extends State<UserProfile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    String _currentphoneNumber;
    String _currentName;
    String _currentEmail;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: customColor,
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => Home(),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (_) => Settings(),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
        title: Text(
          getTranslated(context, 'profile'),
          style: AppTheme.heading.copyWith(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<Users>(
        stream: DatabaseServices(userId: user.uid).userData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            Users userData = snapshot.data;
            return ListView(
              children: [
                proAppBar(width),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    initialValue: userData.name,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelStyle: AppTheme.heading.copyWith(
                        color: customColor,
                      ),
                      labelText: getTranslated(context, 'name'),
                    ),
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      print(val);
                      setState(() {
                        _currentName = val;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    initialValue: userData.phoneNumber,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelStyle: AppTheme.heading.copyWith(
                        color: customColor,
                      ),
                      labelText: getTranslated(context, 'phone_num'),
                    ),
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      _currentphoneNumber = val;
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    initialValue: UserData.pasword,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelStyle: AppTheme.heading.copyWith(
                        color: customColor,
                      ),
                      labelText: getTranslated(context, 'password'),
                    ),
                    obscureText: true,
                    readOnly: true,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    initialValue: userData.email,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelStyle: AppTheme.heading.copyWith(
                        color: customColor,
                      ),
                      labelText: getTranslated(context, 'email'),
                    ),
                    readOnly: true,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.pink[400],
                    child: Text(
                      'Update',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      // DatabaseServices(userId: user.uid).updateUserData(
                      //   _currentphoneNumber ?? userData.phoneNumber,
                      //   _currentName ?? userData.name,
                      //   _currentEmail ?? userData.email,
                      //   UserData.userImageUrl,
                      // );

                      print('update');
                      print(user.uid);
                      print(_currentphoneNumber);
                      print(_currentName);
                      print(_currentEmail);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildTextField({
    String labelText,
    String initialValue,
    bool obscureText,
    bool readOnly,
    Function onChaged,
  }) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8, bottom: 35),
      child: TextFormField(
        initialValue: initialValue,
        onChanged: onChaged,
        obscureText: obscureText,
        readOnly: readOnly,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelStyle: AppTheme.heading.copyWith(
            color: customColor,
          ),
          labelText: labelText,
          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget proAppBar(double width) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 160,
          // color: Colors.amber,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Builder(
                  builder: (context) => Container(
                    height: 80,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: customColor,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(15),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 0,
                right: (width * .4) - 35,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Hero(
                      tag: 'userImg',
                      child: Container(
                        height: 150,
                        width: 150,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage(
                              UserData.userImageUrl,
                            ),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              spreadRadius: 2,
                              blurRadius: 10,
                              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                              offset: Offset(0, 10),
                            ),
                          ],
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            width: 5,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: 0,
                      right: 0,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Container(
                          height: 35,
                          width: 35,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            color: customColor,
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 2,
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.edit,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

output:

```
W/1.raster(21458): type=1400 audit(0.0:115680): avc: denied { search } for name="battery" dev="sysfs" ino=6754 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c231,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs_batteryinfo:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
I/flutter (21458): sddsfs
I/flutter (21458): sddsfsd
I/flutter (21458): sddsfsdd
I/flutter (21458): sddsfsdds
I/flutter (21458): update
I/flutter (21458): HPTelCFX17W84vG8rjrnrlwUiHr2
I/flutter (21458): null
I/chatty  (21458): uid=10231(com.example.vanillia) 1.ui identical 1 line
I/flutter (21458): null
```

Comment: Please edit your question and give it a title that describes your actual problem.

Comment: Update you _currentPhoneNumber inside `setState`.

Comment: @ASADHAMEED oki i do it but also print (number and name) null at i cleck update

Answer (score 0):

You are updating `currentphoneNumber` without using `setState`.

In a stateful widget you need to call `setState` for objects whose state is changed.

```
onChanged: (val) {

print(val);

setState((){

    _currentphoneNumber = val;
    
});
},
```

Comment: oki i do it but also print (number and name) null at i cleck update

Comment: `_currentphoneNumber ` will be null until updated inside of `setState`

Comment: i updating it and it until print null

Comment: Your `phoneNumber` variable is not updated inside `setState`